# Ruby on Rails @article.id and@article.category_id keep getting switched

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone tell me why id and category_id keep getting switched in Rails?? im losing my mind! the console says its correctly but when i get an error it shows that params switches it around. This my controller below:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @article = Article.new
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
end

def create
    @article = Article.new(articles_params)
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    # binding.pry
    @article.category_id = @category.id
    binding.pry
    if @article.save
        redirect_to category_path(@category)
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])

    if @article.update(articles_params)
        redirect_to category_path(@category)
    else
        render :edit
    end
end

def destroy
    # binding.pry
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to category_path(@category)
end

private

def articles_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
end
end
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks fine.

Look below on the request parameters from your screenshot:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "category_id" : 2
}
```

You are looking for `id 1` in the context of your Article controller.
`1` refers to the article with id `1`.
Meanwhile you are looking for a Category with id `2` (category_id 2).

```
Category.find(params[:category_id])
```

The error is saying that it cannot find a Category object with id 2.

The 2 comes from your request. If something is wrong, it's in your request creation.

Comment: Yes but actually it is my first category and my second article. the information is printing out correctly in my rails console.

Comment: As I said: the issue is with the request. You pass the wrong parameters. Can you include the building of your request in the question ?